# How to calculate amplification factor for a recursion formula?

Tags: numerical-methods, recursion

I need to determine the solutions for a recursion formula by using the amplification

$$ax_n - bx_{n+1} = cx_{n+2}$$

where $a,b,c$ are constants and $x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2}$ are iterations.

So far I have that the amplification factor is $A=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$. So substituting this in I get $A^2 - \frac{a}{c} = 0$. However I don't think this is right and don't want to continue down the wrong path so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You assume that the solution is proportional to $A^n$ where $A$ is the amplification factor.  You also have $A=\frac {x_{n+2}}{x_{n+1}}$.  Now substitute that in and you get $a+bA=cA^2$.  Solve the quadratic in $A$, take the greater root, and you have it.

Comment: Thank you, so then the solution would be x=((b+/- root(b^2+4ac))/2a)^n?